# Исключить нажатие кнопок по событию keyup

Tags: jquery

Всем привет. Есть такой скрипт

```
$("#search_articul").keyup(function() {
            //form= $(this).parents("form");
            submitFilter();
        });
```

К сожалению отрабатывает на нажатии всех кнопок. А как исключить отработку при нажатии кнопок ctrl и shift?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#search_articul").keyup(function(e) {
   if ((e.keyCode != 16) && (e.keyCode != 17)) 
       submitFilter();
});
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]